# Return Only with Data

Tags: sql

I was wondering if there would be a way to write a regular `Select * from...` query but only return fields that contain data, as in any columns that are completely NULL don't get returned? I was thinking it might be possible with a temporary table but I'm not sure and a quick google hasn't yielded any results.

Reason being I'm querying a table with hundreds of columns 95% of which are NULL, those few with the data are the ones I need to see.

Comment: imagine your table structure if first row doesn't have any value in first column while second row has value in this first column.

Comment: "any columns that are completely NULL" - as in top to bottom NULL

Comment: Reason for downvote would be nice?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible by default (as far as i know). You can however write simple function which will unset NULL-valued keys from passed array. But i can't see point of it - please give us more informations about Your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with the required column and then use select * from view_name.

```
Create view V_sample
AS
select column1, column2 
from table
```

Then you can do:

```
select * from V_sample
```